# AWAITing a critical property

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have a Cloud Application that uses the excellent [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/) library for Device Detection.

Based on the type of device that is accessing the website, we load different resources.

Up until recently, I had been embedding the service in my Cloud Application. The issue is that it adds 3-5 minutes to every debug routine as the service supports detection of many thousands of devices. The recommended pattern by the .NET team is to load the service into the Cache:

```
var wurflDataFile = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(WurflDataFilePath);
var configurer = new InMemoryConfigurer().MainFile(wurflDataFile);
var manager = WURFLManagerBuilder.Build(configurer);
HttpContext.Current.Cache["WurflManagerCacheKey"] = manager;
```

This 3-5 minute delay was costing us roughly 1-3 hours of productive time across a team of 5 developers (People get up to get a snack, etc every time they deploy, whether locally or to PPE)

In order to speed things up, we recently created an independent Cloud WEB API service that receives the proper information and returns an object with all the information we need. We're getting excellent (less than 30ms) response times from the active service.

The problem I'm facing now, is that I'm not sure how we best change our load routine.

I could make the HomeController `async` and just await the property, but that seems dangerous. What's the best way to handle something like this?

```
public static async Task<Device> GetDevice(RequestInfo requestInfo)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://mysiteurl.com");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
          new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("/api/devicedetection", requestInfo);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Device>();
    }
    return new Device(Device.Default);
}

//Proposed Solution from team as it stands
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string id)
{
    _device = await Device.GetDevice(Request.UserAgent);
    try
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_userName))
        {
            Session.Add("CurrentDevice", _device);
            ViewBag.DeviceType = _device.Type;
            ViewBag.DeviceOs = _device.Os;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Redirect("/Error");
    }
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Looks like you already have a solution.  What's your problem/question?

Comment: Is this an acceptable pattern? There is some debate about ASYNC controllers. What happens if the service takes too long, or goes down? I feel like I have *A* solution, but it may not be the best one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with using `async-await` in a website. If the operations you are performing are naturally asynchronous (e.g I/O) it's much preferable. It lowers the resources being used by your application and improves scalability.<sup>*</sup>

I would recommend keeping to the `async` naming standards and renaming `GetDevice` to `GetDeviceAsync` and also handling exceptions by moving `_device = await Device.GetDevice(Request.UserAgent);` inside the  `try-catch` block

---

<sup>* It could *slightly* increase the duration of each operation, but it allows for a lot more operations concurrently</sup>

Comment: I did not downvote you, but I might disagree with your fineprint note: "It could slightly increase the duration of each operation". Why would it do so?

Comment: @avo the `async` mechanism (state-machine, tasks, etc.) does come with some, very small, cost. `async-await` isn't about speeding up operations, it's about improved utilization of resources and offloading work off of special threads (e.g. GUI thread). More in [Async Performance: Understanding the Costs of Async and Await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456402.aspx)

Comment: That's correct, but I think the advantage of continuing on the same thread where an I/O operation has ended - and thus avoiding a costly thread switch of returning to the initial blocked thread - would beat any overhead possibly introduced by `async` plumbing. I think async code might actually be slightly faster because of that.